# Is there a way to use nbextensions configurator in Google-Colaboratory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I installed nbextensions and its configurator in my first code cell using

```
!pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
!pip install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
!jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

Printing at the end :

```
Enabling: jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
- Writing config: /content/.jupyter
    - Validating...
      jupyter_nbextensions_configurator  OK
Enabling notebook nbextension nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main...
Enabling tree nbextension nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main...
```

The [doc](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator#usage) says to go to the `/nbextensions` page from the root, but on Google-colaboratory it is not possible since we do not have access to the container directly I suppose ...

The `!find / -name nbextensions` prints the following output :

```
/root/.ipython/nbextensions
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_core/tests/dotipython/nbextensions
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jupyter_core/tests/dotipython/nbextensions
/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions
/content/.ipython/nbextensions
```

And if I go looking in the `!ls -l /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions` directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 21 17:08 google.colab
```

Any idea on how to use or connect to the configurator ?

Comment: You can install extensions from a cell command as well [see here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions#3-enablingdisabling-extensions).  I've managed to install several but they don't seem available to the user, possibly because colab is set up a bit different.  Which one do you want to use?  It looks like colab has a bunch built in already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! The question is almost 2 years old and I forgot what I wanted to install :P I since abandonned the use of extensions anyway ... I found myself more efficient with real code. 
Jupyter is good for prototyping or for educating but nothing is less intuitive for others who wants to participate than the variable management in Jupyter :)